# Running hangout app from API console/Sandbox, unable to invite other (test) participants

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, google-hangouts

Hi all: I'm trying to test a hangout app, running from the API Console link/in the Sandbox.

Machines are

```
- Mac OS X,
- latest normal Chrome.
```

Both users are

```
- Google Apps users, 
- added to API Team for hangout project,
- able to see the App Engine application for static files etc.
```

User one is API project owner, user two can view project.

1. As user one, I click the API Console/Sandbox link to start.
2. The plugin starts, and the app starts right away.
3. I click on the App icon at left to hide the app.
4. I click on the blue Invite People button to invite user two.
5. The app frame goes blank, no way to invite user two.

In user one's console, there's only one error, *prior to app startup*:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel
```

Starting with user two, I get two errors--first the following, followed by the above error, followed by app startup:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isLoaded' of undefined
:87
```

The stacktrace of this error goes

```
0d.be :87
init: (program):1
onload :1
0d.load :1
Gg :120
window.jstiming.js :124
(anonymous function) :371
```

... no file names, just line numbers.

I have not gone through the OAuth client ID configuration yet. Is this needed for Sandbox work between two users (as opposed to individually)?

I need a way to get these two users into the same hangout. Eventually I can do this through server-sent URLs (I believe) but for yesterday I need a quick 'n' dirty method.

Many thanks for any insight.

Kirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use Invite, you may want to send the URL of the sandboxed hangout to the other person.

You may also want to skip the sandbox altogether and just publish the code and work with the "public" version.

Comment: Ahh, didn't think of walking the URL over. Thanks for that.

I'm assuming I could make the hangout public but prevent listing in Chrome Web Store until I was finished testing.

Comment: You never actually list it in the Chrome Web Store. You just use the store's authentication to verify you.